# Looking up a list of words into a String in Scala

Tags: string, scala, substring

I need to find if any word from a word list (which could be a Set or List or another structure) is contained (as a sub-string) in another String and I need the best possible performance.

This could be an example:

```
val query = "update customer set id=rand() where id=1000000009;" 
val wordList = Set("NOW(", "now(", "LOAD_FILE(", "load_file(", "UUID(", "uuid(", "UUID_SHORT(",
        "uuid_short(", "USER(", "user(", "FOUND_ROWS(", "found_rows(", "SYSDATE(", "sysdate(", "GET_LOCK(", "get_lock(",
        "IS_FREE_LOCK(", "is_free_lock(", "IS_USED_LOCK(", "is_used_lock(", "MASTER_POS_WAIT(", "master_pos_wait(",
        "RAND(", "rand(", "RELEASE_LOCK(", "release_lock(", "SLEEP(", "sleep(", "VERSION(", "version(")
```

What is the best option to achieve the best performance? I have read about the contains method but it doesn't work for sub-strings. Is the only option to iterate through the list and to use the method indexOf or there is a better option?

Comment: Dylan's answer would be the best. You may improve the performance a little bit if you can guarantee that what you search will be always a word, and first create a **Set* with all words on the `query`.

Comment: Do you just need a yes/no result (`query` has/has-not a sub-string found in `wordList`), or do you want specifics? (Which `wordList` entry? Where in `query`?) Also, are word boundaries important? (`"snow(8 inches)"` will match `"now("`)

Comment: I only need a yes/no result. I used it to find if there is a concrete function (the functions of the wordlist) in a sql query. "snow(8inches)" may return a negative result but I think it will never happen in a query so it is not important for my use case. I think to find the substring in the query is enough. I dont use the last parenthesis of the functions because they can have words inside like your example with 8inches. and I dont want to use regex because is very slow and I need the faster way to do it.

Comment: If you're going to use this fixed list of search strings to look within many other strings, then you can do better than the naive contains/exists approach. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns

Comment: why you past a first line of code? It's related to problem? If not, please, remote it

Comment: The first line of code is a unknown query where I need to check if contains any word of my known word list.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin I think the approach you suggest is the best. With the Aho–Corasick algorithm is possible to achieve (with a dictionary with known words which is my use case) almost linear complexity and this is much better than contains/exist complexity.

Comment: You can up answer. The Aho–Corasick ([Java's variant with dependency link](https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick)) string-matching algorithm formed `fgrep`, but in same cases it can be more slower than more simple algorithm, because of `O(n)` mean about `n*Constant`. But in most cases it should be very fast.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I did a mistake. I was speaking about @The Archetypal Paul answer suggesting special algorithms like aho-corasick. Mikhail Ionkin Its interesting your link to Aho-Corasick algorithm implementation.  Can I use that Java dependency directly in Scala?

Comment: @zamora14 [How to use a Maven repository library with SBT](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-use-maven-repository-library-with-scala-sbt)

Answer (score 4):

For Scala collections, the method to use in order to answer a question like "is there an item in this collection that satisfies my condition?" is [`exists`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html#exists(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean) (scroll up slightly when you get there because the scaladoc pages are weird about linking directly to methods).

Your condition is "does the string (query) *contain* this item (word)?" For this, you can use `String`'s [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method, which comes from Java.

Putting it together, you'll get

```
wordList.exists { word => query.contains(word) }
// or, with some syntax sugar
wordList exists { query.contains }
```

You can also use `.find` instead of `.exists`, which will return an Option containing the first match that was found, instead of just a Boolean indicating whether or not something was found.

```
scala> wordList.exists(query.contains)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> wordList.find(query.contains)
res2: Option[String] = Some(rand()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is advice for solution:

1. Check that you need to optimize it. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."
2. Array is collection with fastest access to element. Use it to increase access's speed.
3. Sometimes use a [ParArray](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/concrete-parallel-collections.html#parallel-array) may increase performance.
4. If it's acceptable, for best performance first cast string to lower case, and remove all UPPER_CASE from set.
5. You can use own "contains" method to find any of substring. E.g., you can group some words by their prefixes (or suffixes) and don't pass all group if next (prev) symbol is different.
6. Use native Java to increase performance (Scala can wrap array)
7. First find all positions of `(`, because all variants related to it. Than you can check last word's symbol.

Sorry for my English. It is not best advice, but I know small amount of people (e.g. on acm.timus.ru) which can write more faster functions at Scala.